# set opacity with color literal in openlayers style

Tags: openlayers-3

In openLayers 3 I take some features in GeoJSON format and create a style for them.

The features have a value of "income" that has values like "red", "blue", "green" etc etc.

So I want to add alpha to the color of the features, but because the color is a word and not RGB I cannot.

I do

```
var color = feature.get('income');

fill: new ol.style.Fill({
   color: [color, 0.75]
})
```

and all the features are black.

Who do I fix this?

Thanks

***Update***

Suppose I change the value of every "income" attribute from a word to an RGB so now is not "blue", but "0,0,127" and then I try to compose a string

```
var color = feature.get('income');
var colorfinal = '[' + color + ',0.3]';

var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
    color: colorfinal
});
```

and still all features are black. Well, beats me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add rgba in you string and remove bruckets. check it here

```
new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
        lineDash: [10, 10],
        width: 3
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks,  this works. I wouldnt even think of adding `rgba`. How do you thought this? Well maybe there is a simpler way, setting the color using a word or rgb and then setting the opacity. Like `var beg = '0,0,127'; var colorfinal = 'rgb(' +beg+  ')'; var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
  color: colorfinal,
  opacity: 0.3
 }); `. But this does not work and I dont see any opacity [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.style.Fill.html). Any tips?

Comment: I think thas the only way. check the documentation http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.style.Fill.html I doesnt accept any opacity attribute. To be honest I didnt think of it on my own. I found it in the docs. check it here the first lines http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.style.html